# Conditional replacement syntax

Tags: replacement

Why does the following expression not do what I expect

```
Array[a, 6, 0] /. a[__?MemberQ[{1, 2}, #] &] -> 0
```

I expect

```
{a{0],0,0,a[3],a{4],a[5]}
```

but I get

```
{a{0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a{4],a[5]}
```

What do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: `Array[a, 6, 0] /. a[__?(MemberQ[{1, 2}, #] &)] -> 0`

Answer (score 3):

You should replace `__?MemberQ[{1, 2}, #] &` with `__?(MemberQ[{1, 2}, #] &)`.
Because the `&` has the *low priority*. So, the pattern is interpreted as part of the function, and not the function as part of the pattern. This can be easily seen using `FullForm`:

```
In[24]:= __?MemberQ[{1, 2}, #] & // FullForm

Out[24]//FullForm= 
 Function[PatternTest[BlankSequence[], MemberQ][List[1, 2], Slot[1]]]
```

vs

```
In[25]:= __?(MemberQ[{1, 2}, #] &) // FullForm

Out[25]//FullForm= 
 PatternTest[BlankSequence[], Function[MemberQ[List[1, 2], Slot[1]]]]
```

Using the modified function, you get

```
Array[a, 6, 0] /. a[__?(MemberQ[{1, 2}, #] &)] -> 0
```

> ```
> {a[0], 0, 0, a[3], a[4], a[5]}
> ```

Comment: @rcollyer, Very nice:-) Thanks a lot

Comment: This should be part of the [common pitfalls for new users](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/52), but I can't seem to find it. Also, I know it is a duplicate, but finding it is difficult, at best. So, I made this as canonical of answer as I could.